# map setting is not working for redirect in nginx

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I have redirect-map.map file which has some url to redirect as below but redirect setting is not working:

```
/jewelry/test/costumes(.*)a1 https://test.com/jewelry/test/costumes.html;
/jewelry/test/glasses(.*)a1 https://test.com/jewelry/test/glasses.html;
/jewelry/test/hats(.*)a1 https://test.com/jewelry/test/hats.html;
```

My test.conf file look like below :

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
map $uri_lowercase $new {
    include /etc/nginx/redirect-map.map;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;

set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
set $MAGE_MODE developer;

fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

proxy_cookie_path /var/www/test/ "/; secure";
proxy_cookie_path /login_redirect "/var/www/test; secure";

location = / {
    if ($new) {
            return 301 $new;
    }
  }   
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name test.com;

set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
set $MAGE_MODE developer;

fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

location = / {
    if ($new) {
            return 301 $new;
    }
  }   


}
```

Comment: A regular expression in a `map` needs to be prefixed with `~` or `~*`.

Comment: Also I don’t see uri_lowercase definition